# Flutter type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' despite having no integer used

Tags: database, string, flutter, async-await, integer

I fixed it once, but it came back I do not understand why I am sure my code is the same before that it works. The main to look out is on the HomeForm.dart, LoginForm.dart and DbHelper.dart but I don't see any issues. Please help me point out the problem or what kind of error is this because in this case I really did not play with any of the variables. It just happened, I have tried uninstalling the app on the phone and reload it still no luck.

DbHelper.dart:

```
import 'package:conferenceApp/Model/UserModel.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Model/specializeModel.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Model/loginModel.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'dart:io' as io;

class DbHelper {
  static Database conference;

  static const String DB_Name = 'conference.db';
  static const String Table_conferenceInfo = 'conferenceinfo';
  static const String Table_specializeArea = 'specializearea';
  static const String Table_login = 'login';

  static const String C_UserID = 'id';
  static const String C_Name = 'name';
  static const String C_UName = 'username';
  static const String C_Email = 'email';
  static const String C_Phone = 'phone';
  static const String C_Role = 'role';

  static const String C_Area = 'area';

  static const String C_Password = 'password';
  static const int Version = 1;
  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (conference != null) {
      return conference;
    }
    conference = await initDb();
    return conference;
  }

  initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, DB_Name);
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: Version, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return db;
  }

  _onCreate(Database db, int intVersion) async {
    await db.execute("CREATE TABLE $Table_conferenceInfo ("
        " $C_UserID INTEGER, "
        " $C_Name TEXT, "
        " $C_UName TEXT, "
        " $C_Email TEXT,"
        " $C_Password TEXT, "
        " $C_Phone INTEGER, "
        " $C_Role TEXT, "
        " PRIMARY KEY ($C_UserID)"
        ")");
    await db.execute("CREATE TABLE $Table_specializeArea ("
        " $C_UserID INTEGER, "
        " $C_Area TEXT )");
    await db.execute("CREATE TABLE $Table_login ("
        " $C_UserID INTEGER, "
        " $C_UName TEXT, "
        " $C_Password TEXT )");
  }

  Future<void> saveData(UserModel user) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res = await dbClient.insert(Table_conferenceInfo, user.toMap());
    return res;
  }

  Future<int> saveData1(specializeModel user) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res1 = await dbClient.insert(Table_specializeArea, user.toMap());
    return res1;
  }

  Future<int> saveData2(loginModel user) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res2 = await dbClient.insert(Table_login, user.toMap());
    return res2;
  }

  Future<UserModel> getLoginUser(String userId, String password) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res =
        await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $Table_conferenceInfo WHERE "
            "$C_UName = '$userId' AND "
            "$C_Password = '$password'");

    if (res.length > 0) {
      return UserModel.fromMap(res.first);
    }

    return null;
  }

  Future<int> updateUser(UserModel user) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res = await dbClient.update(Table_conferenceInfo, user.toMap(),
        where: '$C_UserID = ?', whereArgs: [user.user_id]);
    return res;
  }

  Future<int> deleteUser(String user_id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var res = await dbClient.delete(Table_conferenceInfo,
        where: '$C_UserID = ?', whereArgs: [user_id]);
    return res;
  }
}
```

LoginForm.dart:

```
import 'package:conferenceApp/Model/loginModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Comm/comHelper.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Comm/genLoginSignupHeader.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Comm/genTextFormField.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/DatabaseHandler/DbHelper.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Model/UserModel.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Screens/SignupForm.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'HomeForm.dart';

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _pref = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final _conUserName = TextEditingController();
  final _conPassword = TextEditingController();
  var dbHelper;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dbHelper = DbHelper();
  }

  login() async {
    String uname = _conUserName.text;
    String passwd = _conPassword.text;

    if (uname.isEmpty) {
      alertDialog(context, "Please Enter Username");
    } else if (passwd.isEmpty) {
      alertDialog(context, "Please Enter Password");
    } else {
      await dbHelper.getLoginUser(uname, passwd).then((userData) {
        if (userData != null) {
          setSP(userData).whenComplete(() {
            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeForm()),
                (Route<dynamic> route) => true);
          });
        } else {
          alertDialog(context, "Error: User Not Found");
        }
      }).catchError((error) {
        print(error);
        alertDialog(context, "Error: Login Fail");
      });
    }
  }

  Future setSP(UserModel user) async {
    final SharedPreferences sp = await _pref;

    sp.setString("id", user.user_id);
    sp.setString("name", user.Name);
    sp.setString("username", user.user_name);
    sp.setString("email", user.email);
    sp.setString("password", user.password);
    sp.setString("phone", user.phone);
    sp.setString("role", user.role);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login with Signup'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                genLoginSignupHeader('Login'),
                getTextFormField(
                    controller: _conUserName,
                    icon: Icons.person,
                    hintName: 'Username'),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                getTextFormField(
                  controller: _conPassword,
                  icon: Icons.lock,
                  hintName: 'Password',
                  isObscureText: true,
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: FlatButton(
                    child: Text(
                      'Login',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onPressed: login,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text('Does not have account? '),
                      FlatButton(
                        textColor: Colors.blue,
                        child: Text('Signup'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignupForm()));
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

UserModel.dart:

```
class UserModel {
  String user_id;
  String Name;
  String user_name;
  String email;
  String password;
  String phone;
  String role;

  UserModel(this.user_id, this.Name, this.user_name, this.email, this.password,
      this.phone, this.role);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      'id': user_id,
      'name': Name,
      'username': user_name,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'phone': phone,
      'role': role
    };
    return map;
  }

  UserModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    user_id = map['id'];
    Name = map['name'];
    user_name = map['username'];
    email = map['email'];
    password = map['password'];
    phone = map['phone'];
    role = map['role'];
  }
}
```

SignupForm.dart:

```
import 'package:conferenceApp/Comm/genTextFormFieldNum.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Comm/comHelper.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Comm/genLoginSignupHeader.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Comm/genTextFormField.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/DatabaseHandler/DbHelper.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Model/UserModel.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Model/loginModel.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Screens/LoginForm.dart';

class SignupForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignupFormState createState() => _SignupFormState();
}

class _SignupFormState extends State<SignupForm> {
  final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final _conUserId = TextEditingController();
  final _conUserName = TextEditingController();
  final _conName = TextEditingController();
  final _conEmail = TextEditingController();
  final _conPassword = TextEditingController();
  final _conCPassword = TextEditingController();
  final _conCPhone = TextEditingController();
  final _conRole = TextEditingController();
  var dbHelper;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dbHelper = DbHelper();
  }

  signUp() async {
    String uid = _conUserId.text;
    String uname = _conUserName.text;
    String Name = _conName.text;
    String email = _conEmail.text;
    String passwd = _conPassword.text;
    String phone = _conCPhone.text;
    String role = _conRole.text;
    String cpasswd = _conCPassword.text;

    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      if (passwd != cpasswd) {
        alertDialog(context, 'Password Mismatch');
      } else {
        _formKey.currentState.save();

        UserModel uModel =
            UserModel(uid, Name, uname, email, passwd, phone, role);
        loginModel uModel2 = loginModel(uid, uname, passwd);
        await dbHelper.saveData2(uModel2).then((userData2) {});
        await dbHelper.saveData(uModel).then((userData) {
          alertDialog(context, "Successfully Saved");

          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginForm()));
        }).catchError((error) {
          print(error);
          alertDialog(context, "Error: Data Save Fail");
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Login with Signup'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  genLoginSignupHeader('Signup'),
                  getTextFormFieldNum(
                      controller: _conUserId,
                      icon: Icons.person,
                      hintName: 'User ID'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                      controller: _conUserName,
                      icon: Icons.person_outline,
                      inputType: TextInputType.name,
                      hintName: 'Username'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                      controller: _conName,
                      icon: Icons.person_outline,
                      inputType: TextInputType.name,
                      hintName: 'Name'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                      controller: _conEmail,
                      icon: Icons.email,
                      inputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      hintName: 'Email'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                    controller: _conPassword,
                    icon: Icons.lock,
                    hintName: 'Password',
                    isObscureText: true,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                    controller: _conCPassword,
                    icon: Icons.lock,
                    hintName: 'Confirm Password',
                    isObscureText: true,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormFieldNum(
                    controller: _conCPhone,
                    icon: Icons.phone,
                    hintName: 'Phone Number',
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                    controller: _conRole,
                    icon: Icons.remove_red_eye,
                    hintName: 'Role (Participant, Presenter, Reviewer, Judges',
                  ),
                  // AREA SELECTION
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Signup',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      onPressed: signUp,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text('Does you have account? '),
                        FlatButton(
                          textColor: Colors.blue,
                          child: Text('Sign In'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginForm()),
                                (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

loginModel.dart:

```
class loginModel {
  String user_id;
  String user_name;
  String password;

  loginModel(this.user_id, this.user_name, this.password);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      'id': user_id,
      'username': user_name,
      'password': password
    };
    return map;
  }

  loginModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    user_id = map['id'];
    user_name = map['username'];
    password = map['password'];
  }
}
```

HomeForm.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Comm/comHelper.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Comm/genTextFormField.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/DatabaseHandler/DbHelper.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Model/UserModel.dart';
import 'package:conferenceApp/Screens/LoginForm.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class HomeForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeFormState createState() => _HomeFormState();
}

class _HomeFormState extends State<HomeForm> {
  final _formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Future<SharedPreferences> _pref = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  DbHelper dbHelper;
  final _conUserId = TextEditingController();
  final _conName = TextEditingController();
  final _conDelUserId = TextEditingController();
  final _conUserName = TextEditingController();
  final _conEmail = TextEditingController();
  final _conPassword = TextEditingController();
  final _conCPhone = TextEditingController();
  final _conRole = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserData();

    dbHelper = DbHelper();
  }

  Future<void> getUserData() async {
    final SharedPreferences sp = await _pref;

    setState(() {
      _conUserId.text = sp.getString("id");
      _conDelUserId.text = sp.getString("id");
      _conName.text = sp.getString("name");
      _conUserName.text = sp.getString("username");
      _conEmail.text = sp.getString("email");
      _conPassword.text = sp.getString("password");
      _conCPhone.text = sp.getString("phone");
      _conRole.text = sp.getString("role");
    });
  }

  update() async {
    String uid = _conUserId.text;
    String Name = _conName.text;
    String uname = _conUserName.text;
    String email = _conEmail.text;
    String passwd = _conPassword.text;
    String phone = _conCPhone.text;
    String role = _conRole.text;

    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      UserModel user = UserModel(uid, Name, uname, email, passwd, phone, role);
      await dbHelper.updateUser(user).then((value) {
        if (value == 1) {
          alertDialog(context, "Successfully Updated");

          updateSP(user, true).whenComplete(() {
            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginForm()),
                (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
          });
        } else {
          alertDialog(context, "Error Update");
        }
      }).catchError((error) {
        print(error);
        alertDialog(context, "Error");
      });
    }
  }

  delete() async {
    String delUserID = _conDelUserId.text;

    await dbHelper.deleteUser(delUserID).then((value) {
      if (value == 1) {
        alertDialog(context, "Successfully Deleted");

        updateSP(null, false).whenComplete(() {
          Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginForm()),
              (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  Future updateSP(UserModel user, bool add) async {
    final SharedPreferences sp = await _pref;

    if (add) {
      sp.setString("username", user.user_name);
      sp.setString("Name", user.Name);
      sp.setString("email", user.email);
      sp.setString("password", user.password);
      sp.setString("phone", user.phone);
      sp.setString("role", user.role);
    } else {
      sp.remove('id');
      sp.remove('name');
      sp.remove('username');
      sp.remove('email');
      sp.remove('password');
      sp.remove('phone');
      sp.remove('role');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  //Update
                  getTextFormField(
                      controller: _conUserId,
                      isEnable: false,
                      icon: Icons.person,
                      hintName: 'User ID'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                      controller: _conName,
                      icon: Icons.person,
                      hintName: 'Name'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                      controller: _conUserName,
                      icon: Icons.person_outline,
                      inputType: TextInputType.name,
                      hintName: 'Username'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                      controller: _conEmail,
                      icon: Icons.email,
                      inputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      hintName: 'Email'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                    controller: _conPassword,
                    icon: Icons.lock,
                    hintName: 'Password',
                    isObscureText: true,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                    controller: _conCPhone,
                    icon: Icons.phone,
                    hintName: 'Phone',
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  getTextFormField(
                    controller: _conRole,
                    icon: Icons.remove_red_eye,
                    hintName: 'Role',
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Update',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      onPressed: update,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  ),

                  //Delete

                  getTextFormField(
                      controller: _conDelUserId,
                      isEnable: false,
                      icon: Icons.person,
                      hintName: 'User ID'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text(
                        'Delete',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      onPressed: delete,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be issue with creating **Table_conferenceinfo**.Because here you are using two columns that have integer types.

```
  " $C_UserID INTEGER, "
    " $C_Phone INTEGER, "
```

and in your UserModel , you are using everything with String data type.
Maybe this can be an issue.

Comment: No, I have changed the data type on the table to be TEXT it still has the error,  however, if I change the String uid or phone into int using parse like int uid = int.parse(_conUserID) , I dont get the error but the data are not pushed into setSP function